# C++ error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
float findSimilarityScore(string A, string B)
{
    string C;
    if (A.length() != B.length())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (A.length() == 0 and B.length() == 0)
    {
       return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; A.length() - 1; i = i+1)
        {
            if (A[i] == B[i])
            {
                C.append(A[i]);
            }
            if (A[i] != B[i])
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
    cout << C << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    findSimilarityScore("DDS","DAS");
}
```

when i try to run my code, my IDE show this:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/hmwk4/hmwk4-1.cpp: In function ‘float findSimilarityScore(std::string, std::string)’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/hmwk4/hmwk4-1.cpp:24:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Why?
I want : if the first char in A is same to the first char in B, then add this char to the string C. if the second char in A is same to the second char in B, then add this char to the string C. And so on.

Comment: `for (i = 0; A.length() - 1; i = i+1)` the condition is not a comparision, the increment can just be a ++, the `int` can be inline with the for loop. I don't know what you wouldn't want to look at the last character of the string. You should probably use a size type. `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < A.length(); ++i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
C.append(A[i]);
```

[`std::string::append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) has no overload that takes a single `char`.  Use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) instead:

```
C.push_back(A[i]);
```

This will fix your compilation error, but your function is still logically incorrect.  It returns `0` the first time it finds any character that doesn't match between the two strings, and if the two strings are identical then it will invoke undefined behavior by reaching the end of a non-void function without returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

`string::append()` with a single parameter is expecting a string argument, you are passing a single `char`.  Try

```
C.append(1, A[i]);
```

Also, once you find a non-matching char, you return without printing the new string.  Move the `cout` just before the `return`

```
if (A[i] != B[i])
{
    cout << C << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And be sure to add a return at the end of your function in case you don't find any characters which are unequal.